# Signal not received by script run using sh -c

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a script which sleeps for 3 minutes before running a time consuming command. I want the script to exit if it receives `SIGINT` only while it is sleeping, and not when it is executing the long running command. This is to make sure that only one instance of the time consuming command is running at a given instant of time.

Here's `myscript.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'exit' INT
sleep 180 &
wait
trap '' INT

# Long running command
/etc/init.d/myd sync
```

Here's how I run it:

```
kill -INT `pgrep myscript.sh` 2>/dev/null; ! pgrep -x "myscript.sh" > /dev/null && /opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh &
```

Now this works as expected, even on subsequent runs. i.e.

1. It runs the script if it isn't running.
2. Stops the script (send `SIGINT`), and restart it, if the script was running but hadn't yet executed the long running command.
3. Does nothing if the script was running and executing the long running command.

However, when I run the same one liner using `sh -c`:

```
sh -c 'kill -INT `pgrep myscript.sh` 2>/dev/null; ! pgrep -x "myscript.sh" > /dev/null && /opt/my/scripts/myscript.sh &'
```

It starts the script if it wasn't previously running, but it just doesn't seem to be able to stop the script.

I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the command is killing the script? As in "yes, I used an echo command in the signal handler" or "yes, I watched as the pids changed" certain? In my bash, running the script like that creates a process that won't match the pgrep at all. (/bin/bash /path/to/myscript.sh)

Answer (score 0):

So I had to modify your command paths a bit, but I believe this does what you want. But first, the modifications I needed to make to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Make sure we know when the trap fires. 
trap 'printf "quiting with return code %d\n" "$?"; exit' INT
sleep 180 &
wait
trap '' INT

# Long running command
/usr/bin/sleep 86400
```

Then, I was able to do what you wanted by changing your second command like this:

```
sh -c 'set -x; (exec kill --verbose -INT $(pgrep myscript.sh) 2>/dev/null); ! pgrep -x "myscript.sh" > /dev/null && /tmp/myscript.sh &'
```

And once you've verified running it that way works as expected, you can remove the printf statement from the first trap in the script and run the command like this:

```
 sh -c '(exec kill -INT $(pgrep myscript.sh) 2>/dev/null); ! pgrep -x "myscript.sh" > /dev/null && /tmp/myscript.sh &'
```

Without the parens on the first statement in the above command, which makes it run in a subshell, the `sh` process will be replaced with the `kill` process and the second statement wouldn't run.